# Android Display images from url from api call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

> Note: Don't worry about xamarin almost everything they ported exactly
>   from java.

I developing an android app using xamarin. In HomeFragment i have 3 Tabs (Pager Sliding Tab Strip)
Here in each tab i can get image url along with additional information through API.

example (JSON Output):

```
[  
   {  
      "img":"http:\/\/example.com\/image.jpg",
      "info":[  
         "additional info"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "img":"http:\/\/example.com\/image2.jpg",
      "info":[  
         "additional info"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "img":"http:\/\/example.com\/image3.jpg",
      "info":[  
         "additional info"
      ]
   }
]
```

What i need is i want to display these images I'm Completely new here can you please point me how to do.

Currently Using Components

- Android Support Library v4
- Pager Sliding Tab Strip
- Android Support Library v7 Appcompact
- Android Support Library v7 CardView
- Json.Net

Comment: refer this link:http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Comment: @krunalshah It guide to shows only one image.. but in my case i don't know how many images i get in the api request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about xamarian, we do in android as below:(i guess you are able to read url from that json string)

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(image_url).getContent());
```

If it will work in xamarian, then you can use it, but do it inside Asyntask.

Have a look in this [example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-load-image-from-internet.html).

Look at this [example](http://jmsliu.com/1431/download-images-by-asynctask-in-listview-android-example.html), which is showing downloading multiple images from multiple urls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [this](https://github.com/jacksierkstra/Picasso) or [this](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for Picasso Library. They will help you a lot to work on images for images download and cache it without any extra efforts to manage images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any external api available for image downloading and cache them locally for fast display of images.

Go through below API, may help you -

1 AQuery - [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)

2. Universal-Image-Loader - [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

hope it will help you.